# How to color only two divs of the same class or ID?

Tags: html, css

My site is divided in blocks, and each left blocks have class block_1 and on the right part of the page have block_2.

How can I change only first div with block_1 class? .block1:nth-child(1){background-color:red;} works, but at all divs with block_1 class

Comment: Please see [ask]. Your question needs improvement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's better to split the whole site into seperate sections and then use the `nth-child` property to change the colors. I have attached a demo below

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.block-1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #6200ee;
}
.block-2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #762fff;
}

.container:nth-child(1) .block-1 {
  background-color: #212121;
}
.container:nth-child(3) .block-1 {
  background-color: #212121;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block-1"></div>
  <div class="block-2"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="block-1"></div>
  <div class="block-2"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="block-1"></div>
  <div class="block-2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the details you have given your class as `block_1` but the css code has `block1` without the underscore`_`.

Eg If all your `block_1`'s where nested under a div with an ID of 'block_1_container` your scss file could look something like

```
#block_1_container .block_1:first-child {
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is, looking at your title, don't ever have two `id`'s that are the same, they should always be unique. Second thing is, if you edit your question to include the HTML and CSS you are using then hopefully somebody can give you a more reasonable answer than this one.....

From what I can tell you want to add a background colour to only the first div which has the class `block_1`

This should work in your CSS

```
.block_1:first-child{
   background: red;
}
```